# Dispatch an action after all actions are finished in Redux Observable

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

can you please give me an advice how to wait for multiple Redux dispatches and then do some action? Common scenario is initialization of app (eg. wait for FETCH_SOMETHING_SUCCESS and FETCH_ELSE_SUCCESS and then dispatch APP_INIT_SUCCESS).

Something like...

```
  export const appInitSuccessEpic = (action$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    whenAllDispatched('FETCH_ONE', 'FETCH_SECOND'),
    map(() => { type: 'APP_INIT_SUCCESS' })
  )
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [zip](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html) operator.

> After all observables emit, emit values as an array

```
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';

export const appInitSuccessEpic = (action$) => 
 zip(
    action$.pipe(ofType("FETCH_THIS_SUCCESS")),
    action$.pipe(ofType("FETCH_ELSE_SUCCESS"))
  )
 .pipe(mapTo({ type: 'APP_INIT_SUCCESS' }))
```

Comment: Oh my god. It's so easy and it works! Thank you so much!

Comment: @pneme rx has a lot of useful operators out of the box. the more I learn it, the more I enjoy it. =)